# Getting 'type X is not a subtype of type Y in type cast' without call stack

Tags: dart

I see error in console without call stack:

```
flutter: [ERROR]: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>' in type cast
```

Is there a way to enable call stack for such type of errors, so that I can find the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this exact error it helps to search for  `as Map<String, Object>` in the code and replace the cast with `.cast<String, Object>()` as
[the article](https://medium.com/dartlang/gradual-null-safety-migration-for-large-dart-projects-85acb10b64a9) suggests.

But, yes, it would be helpful if the call stack could be enabled.